# Does Tycho work with Eclipse 3.5

Tags: eclipse, osgi, tycho, maven-3

I've finally got round to looking at [Tycho](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Tycho+project+overview) (a bridge between Maven 3 and OSGi), but I am not getting very far. Following this [tutorial](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/tycho+technology+demo+script) I have downloaded Tycho [0.3.0-DEV-1819](http://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/tycho-pseudo-releases/org/codehaus/tycho/tycho-distribution/0.3.0-DEV-1819/) and the tychodemo.zip and unpacked them both as instructed. I have a 1.5.0_15 JDK set as JAVA_HOME.

When I run (without the newline):

```
c:\tycho\bin\mvn org.codehaus.tycho:maven-tycho-plugin:generate-poms 
    -DgroupId=tycho.demo -Dtycho.targetPlatform=c:/eclipse-3.5
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/classworlds/Launcher
```

Normally I'd spend a bit of time debugging, but as the tutorial says to use Eclipse 3.3.2 I'm wondering if the problem is me using Eclipse 3.5.

Can anybody confirm the Eclipse version is the issue so I can go and download the old Eclipse version? Or even better point me at an up to date Tycho for dummies guide? (the one I'm following is 11 months old)

Answer (score 5):

Now I feel foolish, as soon as I clicked `Ask Your Question` it occurred to me that Tycho's `mvn.bat` was inheriting my `M2_HOME` environment variable (set to a Maven-2.2.0 install). Setting `M2_HOME` to point at `c:\tycho` got past the problem.

The second build (packaging the site) will run against Eclipse 3.5 and generate a sensible looking site. I've yet to confirm that it will actually run on the target platform.

Hopefully this will at least help the next person...

Comment: Thanks, I shall wear it with shame